# Found unwanted token

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm trying to write a street address parser using pyparsing. The sticking point has been capturing more than one `Word` in the street name without greedily capturing the suffix (e.g. AVE, BLVD, ST). This is what I have so far:

```
DIRS = ['NORTH', 'N', 'SOUTH', 'S', 'EAST', 'E', 'WEST', 'W']
SUFFIXES = ['ST', 'AVE', 'BLVD', 'RD']

primary_num = pp.Word(pp.alphanums)
predir = pp.Optional(pp.oneOf(DIRS) + pp.Optional(pp.Suppress('.')))
suffix = pp.Optional(pp.oneOf(SUFFIXES) + pp.Optional(pp.Suppress('.')))
postdir = pp.Optional(pp.oneOf(DIRS) + pp.Optional(pp.Suppress('.')))
street_name = pp.OneOrMore(~suffix + ~postdir + pp.Word(pp.alphanums))
line_1 = primary_num + predir + street_name + suffix + postdir
```

If I run this against 123 GEORGE WASHINGTON AVE I get an error:

```
pyparsing.ParseException: Found unwanted token, [{Re:('ST|AVE|BLVD|RD') [Suppress:(".")]}] (at char 4), (line:1, col:5)
```

This error sounds like the G of GEORGE is matching `Re:('ST|AVE|BLVD|RD')`. Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: `DIRS` is a list of directional keywords -- I added this into the question.

Comment: You can compare notes with a street address parser on the pyparsing wiki examples page: http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/streetAddressParser.py/135329743/streetAddressParser.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by adding some debugging to your parser:

```
predir.setName("predir").setDebug()
street_name.setName("street_name").setDebug()
```

You see that you are matching the optional predir. Instead of defining optionality at the predir, suffix, and postdir definitions, define them as optional in the definition of line_1.

```
line_1 = primary_num + pp.Optional(predir) + street_name + 
            pp.Optional(suffix) + pp.Optional(postdir)
```

You'll also find that your definition of dirs and suffixes should treat them as keywords instead of the Literal-type matching that oneOf does. Instead, use CaselessKeywords:

```
predir = pp.MatchFirst(map(pp.CaselessKeyword,DIRS)) + pp.Optional(pp.Suppress('.'))
suffix = pp.MatchFirst(map(pp.CaselessKeyword,SUFFIXES)) + pp.Optional(pp.Suppress('.'))
postdir = pp.MatchFirst(map(pp.CaselessKeyword,DIRS)) + pp.Optional(pp.Suppress('.'))
```

Lastly, look at grouping the multiple words in the street name, to keep them separate from any pre or post elements:

```
street_name = pp.Group(pp.OneOrMore(~suffix + ~postdir + pp.Word(pp.alphanums)))
```

With these changes, we can get this result:

```
['123', ['GEORGE', 'WASHINGTON'], 'AVE']
```